# iDeal Payment Gateway PHP script

Tags: php, payment, gateway

I have visited the link http://www.ideal.nl, looking for integrating PHP - iDeal payment gateway for an e-commerce website. However, I did not locate the PHP code / API from there. Also there is no provision to create a test/sandbox account to access the required keys and credentials. Please help me.

Comment: probably good to have a thread here on Stackoverflow, but you should also contact them directly (and link to this thread)

Comment: How to contact them? There is no contact phone number/ email/ support chat facility. Need your help.

Comment: maybe this one: info@currence.nl (listed at http://www.ideal.nl/banken/?s=promo&lang=eng-GB )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ideal.nl/acceptant/?s=hoe#q1

You need to contact a bank, or a Collecterende Payment Service Providers (CPSP’s) for the implementation. See here for a list of accredited banks or CPSP's:
http://www.currence.nl/nl-NL/OverOnzeProducten/LicentieEnCertificaathouders/Pages/iDEAL.aspx

EDIT: quick google search: 
http://www.ideal-simulator.nl/ideal-professional-implementatie-handleiding.html (DUTCH)